# Актуальность изучения Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, visual-basic

Вот скажите, я учу примерно 3-4 месяца VB 6.0 и .NET, но хочу не просто делать программки для себя, а стать программистом и зарабатывать на этом деньги, стоит ли продолжать его учить или перейти на C++ или С#?

Comment: Однозначно учите C#...
<br>
<small><a href="http://www.prooflink.it/">пруфлинк</a></small>

Answer (score 5):

Актуальность низкая. Для .NET можно прекрасно писать код на C#, а этот язык имеет много общего синтаксически и стилистически с одной стороны с C++, а с другой - с Java. А VB стоит особняком. Поэтому изучая C#, вы частично изучаете C++ и Java, а изучая VB, - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что разница между VB.NET и C# только в выразительности языка, и в пользу С#, то учите уже последний.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше VB конечно был "слабым" языком. Но при выпуске .NET microsoft сильно улучшили его, добавили разные плюшки и т.п. По поводу акутальности, в России я думаю что нет, лучше учить С++ или C#. На западе говорят много VB.NET программистов, но вот в странах СНГ особо не видать. Даже смотря вакансии можно сделать об этом вывод.

Answer (score 0):

Переучится на C# не составит труда, надо только привыкнуть к новому синтакису. На VB.Net работу найти будет крайне тяжело!

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какую работу. Если место где совместная работа над проектом - то да, трудновато. Если место где вам дают задачу для автоматизации производства - а на чем писать не имеет значения - главное результат, то знания VB.net позволят быстро создавать небольшие приложения.
Конечно же в идеале лучше C++/C#

Answer (score 0):

В отличие от США, актуальность VB NET в России низкая (так уж у нас воспринимают его название), хотя вакансии есть все равно. C# легко изучается после Vb net. Нужно разве что привыкнуть к тому, что C# строго относится к работе с данными. Насчет С++ - процесс разработки будет более долгий, на C# аналогичный софт написать можно в разы быстрее. К тому же если работать на net - С# это "родной" язык платформы.
Мой совет: учите все:) После C# все остальное как по маслу пойдет.